# how to check each checkbox in gridview

Tags: c#, database, gridview, checkbox

```
<asp:GridView ID="science_tab" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"       ShowHeader="false" class="subjects_tab">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="sciencefees_check" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("sub_name") %>' ></asp:CheckBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<label class="rsperhr" for="sciencefees_text">Rupees</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="sciencefees_text" runat="server" Width="40px"  ></asp:TextBox>
    <label class="rsperhr" for="sciencefees_text">Per Hour</label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

there may be like 10 items in my subjects table therefor 10 check-boxes...

i want the C# code which checks all the check-boxes separately and give the checked ones to me so i can insert them in my database...

Answer (score 2):

Following code will give you the list of checked ckeckbox's id.

```
List<int> checkedIDs = new List<int>();

foreach (GridViewRow row in grid1.Rows)
{
  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkStatus");
  if (chk.Checked){
   checkedMsgIDs.Add(int.Parse(grid1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use javaScript code as follows :

**In aspx page**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function checkAllOnGrid() {
    varintRowCount=document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdCount').value;
    var chkAll = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdata_ctl01_chkAll')
    var iStartItemIndex = 2;

    if (chkAll.checked == true) {
        for (i = iStartItemIndex;
             i < parseInt(intRowCount) + parseInt(iStartItemIndex) ; i++) {
            if (i > 9) {
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdata_ctl" + i
                                        + "_" + "ChkAction").checked = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdata_ctl0" + i
                                        + "_" + "ChkAction").checked = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (i = iStartItemIndex;
             i < parseInt(intRowCount) + parseInt(iStartItemIndex) ; i++) {
            if (i > 9) {
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdata_ctl" + i
                                        + "_" + "ChkAction").checked = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdata_ctl0" + i
                                        + "_" + "ChkAction").checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function unCheckHeader() {
    var chkAll=document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdata_ctl01_chkAll')
    if (chkAll.checked == true) { chkAll.checked = false; }
}
</script>
```

Now take your textbox with ID= hdcount and your checkboxes in gridview

**Now in aspx.cs page**

```
protected void fillgrid() {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = obj.FillGrid();
    gvdata.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    gvdata.DataBind();
    hdCount.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
}
```

here `obj.FillGrid();` is your method in which you are calling your values from backend through Stored Procedures.